# htaccess - 2 правила

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите написать правило

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/(.*)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/routes.php [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Всего то нужно

- site.com/ - перенаправить на папку **/public**
- site.com/api/ - перенаправить на папку **/app/routes.php**
- site.com/api/sub/sub - так же перенаправить на папку **/app/routes.php**